# Saving enum into mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, morphia

Is there a way to save enum into the mongoDB? I want to save something like:

```
public enum SnapshotType {
  EVENT,
  MEMORY
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I assume you mean saving an enum value into a collection.

Basically, you just add it into your entity model, like so:

```
@Document(collection = "MyEntity ")
public class MyEntity {
   public SnapshotType snapshotType;
}
```

It will store it as a string in mongo, and automagically convert when you read it out.

Comment: Thanks I think my problem is JAXB related and not MongoDB.

Comment: The problem with saving as a STRING is that it takes more space in BSON and in the index. It would be great to be able to marshal these into an int32 or smaller.

Answer (score 1):

Just save the result. There are no schemas in mongo.